# QPlainTextEdit: How to overwrite the text at the cursor instead of moving it forward

Tags: qt, insert, overwrite, qtextedit

I have a `QPlainTextEdit` that is supposed to display process output. But when the process outputs CR to reset the line, i struggle to implement the same behaviour the terminal would do.

I basically need to do the same as if user pressed `Home`, then `Insert`, and then `Ctrl+V` with the new text in the clipboard.

I tried

```
textEdit->setOverwriteMode( true );
textEdit->moveCursor( QTextCursor::StartOfLine );
textEdit->insertPlainText( newText );
```

but it does not work as expected. The text is still inserted, moving the existing text in front of the cursor forward, instead of overwriting it.

What else can i do to achieve what i need?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly. So you actually only want to replace a word or text without the existing text being moved in one direction but being replaced.

So you can do that as follows. With an input (eg QLineEdit) you insert the word. The QPlainTextEdit has a `find()` function that returns `true` or `false` if the word is found.
with `cursor.movePosition()` you iterate over the position you need. The text to be replaced is swapped with the new text.

here is a small example:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString searchWord = ui->lineEdit->text();
    if(ui->plainTextEdit->find(searchWord, QTextDocument::FindWholeWords))
    {
        QString updateWord = "YourWord/text";    // Your new Word here
        QTextCursor cursor = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor();

        // for lines just use: QTextCursor::StartOfLine
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfLine, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1);

        cursor.insertHtml("<p style=\"background-color:red;color:white;white-space:pre\">" + updateWord + "</p>");
        ui->plainTextEdit->insertPlainText(cursor.selectedText());

        ui->plainTextEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
    }
}
```

[image]

Or even shorter:

```
    QString searchWord = ui->lineEdit->text();
    if(ui->plainTextEdit->find(searchWord, QTextDocument::FindWholeWords))
    {
        QString updateWord = "YourWord/text";    // Your new Word here
        QTextCursor cursor = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor();

        // for single words, just use: QTextCursor::StartOfWord
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfWord, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1);
        ui->plainTextEdit->insertPlainText(updateWord);
    }
```

Comment: Uhm, no, i don't want to search for anything. I just want to insert text at my current cursor position as if Insert key was pressed, but programatically, not by actually typing into the text edit.